# MS Graph throws 401 when uploading a file to another user’s OneDrive share

Tags: node.js, axios, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I have been working on this simple thing for 3 days, I need some wise advice:

I need to send a file to another user’s OneDrive share from Node.js.

- In Azure I made sure I have the appropriate permissions:
  Files.ReadWrite.All of type Application
  Files.ReadWrite.All of type Delegated
- Also I added the Optional Claims:
  act - User’s account status in tenant – token type: Access

Then I get an Access Token by calling MSAL ConfidentialClientApplication and then acquireTokenByClientCredential, like this:

```
function generateTokenPromise() {
  let config = {
    auth: {
      clientId: applicationId,
      authority: msOnlineBaseUrl + '/' + tenantId,
      clientSecret: clientSecretValue,
    },
    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
          console.log(message);
        },
        piiLoggingEnabled: false,
        logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
      }
    }
  };

  // Create msal application object
  let cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

  let clientCredentialRequest = {
    tenant: tenantId, 
    client_id: applicationId,
    scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],
    client_secret: clientSecretValue,
    azureRegion: "centralus",
    skipCache: true,
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
  };

  return cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(clientCredentialRequest)
}
```

The token is good, it allows me to work on other user’s account:

- I can read the content of the root and child folders.
- I can read the info of drive-items, both files and folders.
- I can Create a Folder in the other account.

But, when when I try to create a file, the application gives me a HTTP Error Code 401:  Unauthorized client error status response. Which does not make sense. I have the proper authentication, the token is good, otherwise it would not allow to do the other functions.

To create the request, I am using a Node.js FormData, with a Buffer. I stripped down the code, trying to make it work:

```
function uploadBinaryFile(req, res) {
  let token
  generateTokenPromise()
  .then(tokenResponse => {
    // token = tokenResponse.accessToken
    return receiveBinaryFilePromise(req)
  })
  .then(async buffer => {
    let microsoftUserId = 'LidiaH@appsname.onmicrosoft.com'
    let foundFolderName = 'found-folder'
    let foundFolderId = '01S2X...TOETQ'  // this is the found-folder's Folder Id
    let filename = "new-file.jpg"
    let url = new URL(`/users/${microsoftUserId}/drive/items/${foundFolderId}:/${filename}:/content`, msGraphBaseUrl)
    // let url = new URL(`/users/${microsoftUserId}/drive/root:/${foundFolderName}/${filename}:/content`, msGraphBaseUrl)
    
    let form = new FormData()
    // form.append('uploadFile',  buffer)
    form.append('field', 'a,b,c', 'blah.csv');    // TODO: this is a test, use the buffer later

    let headersConfig = {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
      ...form.getHeaders()
    }
    return axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: url.toString(),
      data: form,
      headers: headersConfig 
    })
  })
  .then(thing => {
    console.log('Success!')
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
 }
```

I am suspicious of what axios is doing to launch the request. I have tried changing the headerConfig and the URL, but I am running out of ideas and time.

I also read about the FormData, but I think it is good.

Do you know how to do this? Can you suggest an article? A work around? Some guiding light to the end of the tunnel?

Thanks
Luis.

Comment: You are using `POST`, while the documentation suggests to use `PUT`. Did you ever try to upload a file via Postman?

Comment: @MarioVarchmin, you were totally right. I changed it to PUT and then tried it in Postman. I added the file to the Body as a Binary file, then tried, after fixing the request, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: I am happy to hear that it is working for you now.

Comment: Hello @MarioVarchmin, Could you please  post your suggestion as an answer as it has worked for DigitalOnion, it will help other community members.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content?view=odsp-graph-online) suggests using the `PUT` method, while you are using `POST`.